# Bootstrap Nav Menu hover dropdown issues

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The following is a screenshot of navbar PSD I want to achieve:

[image: screenshot]

First of all, my navbar dropdown is displayed when I hover on it.

I have the following JS for it:

```js
$('.navbar .dropdown').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideDown(150);
}, function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideUp(105)
});
```

#### [Here's an example on bootply](http://www.bootply.com/rlf0Wsbtln)

Now when I navigate to a link in the dropdown of a main menu item, the main menu items don't have the styles applied to it (color & border).

Any thoughts?

Also, any thoughts on achieving the desired navbar dropdown as in PSD? Here are my issues with the top border of the dropdown list and the bottom border of the main menu.

I tried the following code for making it as in PSD using the following code. But no luck.

```css
#myNavbar ul li.dropdown a:hover, 
#myNavbar ul li.dropdown a:active {
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 1001;
  position: static;
}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: just add this style in css `#myNavbar ul li:hover a:not(:only-child){
  color: #ffba00;
}`   http://www.bootply.com/faBSeWww5R the li was not changing the color because the styles were only for `a` on `:hover` not `li`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of logical issues with the way you've implemented borders. Some have more specific selectors and others are not overriding key styles. Then lastly, you are missing some styles.

[**Fork on Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/Rw5uGYwIQp)

Remove the border attribute from these styles:

```
#myNavbar ul li a {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #434343;
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    border:1px solid #fff;
}
#myNavbar ul li a:hover, #myNavbar ul li a:active, #myNavbar ul li a:focus {
    background: #fff;
    color: #ffba00;
    position: static;
    z-index: 1001;
    border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
}
```

Also to better match your graphic you need to add some padding to `.dropdown-menu` like so:

```
#myNavbar .dropdown-menu {
    z-index: 999;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -1px;
    background: #fff;
    padding:20px;
}
```

Then, with the adjustments above, you then have an issue with `:hover` causing a 'jumping' effect because of style attribute `border:0` on `a:hover`

So, remove the `border-***: 0` attributes in the following CSS class:

```
#myNavbar .dropdown-menu li a:hover {
    border-top: 0;
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    color: #ffba00;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #d6d6d6 !important;
}
```

Oh and one more thing to match the image you'll need to remove the border on the last link element in the dropdown menu. You can do this with the `:last-child` CSS selector to detect the last list element in the drop-down and apply a special style to its child link tag:

```
#myNavbar .dropdown-menu li:last-child a {
  border:none !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tips!

http://screencast.com/t/1wxVnvjwt

My concerns are with why the main menu is not highlighted when the mouse pointer is on the dropdown of the main item.

Comment: That's easy just add a color style to #myNavbar .dropdown:hover>a.dropdown-toggle

Comment: Perfect! 
Thanks. :)

Any thoughts on the border to be replicated?

Comment: You mean the irregular shape? On the dropdown-toggle make sure there is no bottom border then use z-index to put it in front and use margin-top:-1px on the dropdown-menu to bump it up behind the toggle.

Comment: Hi,
I updated the bootply code. But seems to be of no use.

http://www.bootply.com/Rw5uGYwIQp